# How to set an event for a ToastButton?

Tags: c#, uwp, toast

Hey I want a toast notification with a `Textbox` and a `Button` but I have no idea how I can set an action for the `Button`.
I have a `variable` and when I click the `Button` the text in the `Textbox` should be saved in the variable.

```
new ToastContentBuilder()
    .AddArgument("conversationId", 9813)
    .AddText("Kein name eingegeben!")
    .AddInputTextBox("nameBox", "Bitte name hier eingeben")
    .AddButton(new ToastButton()
    .SetContent("Bestätigen")
    .AddArgument("action", "apply")
    .SetBackgroundActivation())
    .Show();
```

This is what I created for now.
I hope someone can help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The official document mentions ”When the user clicks your notification (or a button on the notification with foreground activation), your app's App.xaml.cs OnActivated will be invoked, and the arguments you added will be returned.” So you could refer to this part know [how to handle activation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/shell/tiles-and-notifications/send-local-toast?tabs=uwp#step-3-handling-activation).

Answer (score -1):

in Xamarin?

first, add namespace: `using Xamarin.Essentials;`

then put bellow code into `OnCreate()` method in your Activity

```
Platform.Init(bundle);
```

Then use bellow code for dialogue;

```
string result = await DisplayPromptAsync("Question 1", "What's your name?");
```

[image]

Comment: Based on class names I think this question relates to UWP.

Comment: @SnowGroomer maybe, it would be UWP as you say.